# Small Issue PHP Pagination Mathematics Help

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a small problem with my PHP pagination, I have 6 records and I display 2 at a time, when I click on next and it displays from 2 to 4 records, that works fine, But to display from 4 to 6 records, that does not work. I am not sure what im doing wrong. Anyone have any ideas ? the problem is to do with the calculation for the Next records to be displayed

```
<?php
$per_page = 2;
$start = $_GET['start'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Directory");
$record_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
$record_count = round($record_count / $per_page);

if(!$start) {
    $start = 0;
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Directory LIMIT $start,$per_page") or     die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($query);
// Output Records here

// Setup next and previous button variables
$prev = $start - $per_page;
$next = $start + $per_page;

echo '<p> <h4>';
if($prev < 0) {
    echo 'Previous';
} else {
    echo '<a href="directory.php?start='.$prev.'>Previous</a>';
}

echo ' ' . $start . ' of ' . $record_count;

if($next < $record_count) {
    echo ' <a href="directory.php?start='.$next.'>Next</a>';
} else {
    echo ' Next';
}
echo '</h4> </p>';
?>
```

Comment: You can test out whats happening on http://gebsbo.limewebs.com/directory/directory.php since my explanation skills are not all that great

Comment: What happens when you do rows 4-6?  What is the URL that gets navigated to for it?

Comment: When I do rows 4-6 it doesnt allow me to go to the next and final set of records

Comment: @Gebbo, If the problem is fixed, then upvote & accept the answer.

Comment: its not fixed unfortunately something else came up, when records are changed to display 3 at a time out of six then i cant view the last 3 records, changed the next coding a bit to if($next <= $record_count) {

Comment: $start should be `$start = intval($_GET['start']);` and $record_count should be from `SELECT count(*) FROM Directory` query

Comment: NEVER use mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"); followed by mysql_num_rows just to get the record count, but either use `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT x,y` followed by `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` or use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` to retrieve the record count. Refer to the [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) docs for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a formatting issue.  When I look at your source for the URL http://gebsbo.limewebs.com/directory/directory.php?start=1 I see:

```
<br /><p> <h4>Previous 1 of 4 <a href="directory.php?start=3>Next</a></h4> </p> </body>
```

It looks like you're missing a quote on the href attribute.

In your code, you want:

```
echo '<a href="directory.php?start='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';
```

and

```
echo ' <a href="directory.php?start='.$next.'">Next</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks, I also changed the Next button coding a bit as well to if($next <= $record_count) {. The problem seems to be now fixed, thank you all for the help!

Comment: is whatI would like to say, but if i change the number of records to display to 3 out of 6 then the next button doesnt appear, im going to try if($next - 1 < $record_count){

Comment: Updated next code to,

if(!($start >= $record_count - $page_per)) {
     echo ' <a href="directory.php?start='.$next.'">Next</a>';
    } else {
     echo ' Next';
    }

So it now works to an extent

Answer (score 0):

use this code for calculating :

```
$num = 10; // number of items on page
$p = $_GET['page']; // the var that comes from url (for ex: htttp://..../xxx.php?page=3)
$r = mysql_query(" select * from your_table ");

$posts=mysql_num_rows($r); // total posts
$total=(($posts-1)/$num)+1; // toatal pages
$total=intval($total);
$p=intval($p);
if(empty($p) or $p<0 or !isset($p)) $p=1;
if($p>$total) $p=$total;
$start=$p*$num-$num;

// here print the html for pagination (for ex: htttp://...../xxx.php?page=1 .. 2 ...3 .... and so on ...) you can make a for() here

$r = mysql_query(" select * from your_table limit ".$start.", ".$num);
while (....) {
.....
}
```